# Does operative systems installation order matters?

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, windows-installation, windows-server-2012-r2

Right now, I have a PC with Windows 10.

I installed a second hard drive into the computer.

I would like to add Windows Server 2012 R2 on it and keep Windows 10 installed and operational in its current disk.

Would this installation affect the Windows 10 booting process?

If not (meaning that I would be able to boot any of those two operative systems after installing Windows Server 2012), what would happen if I decide to re-install Windows 10 later on? Would this affect the Windows 2012 installation and its booting process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timmy Jim's answer is correct for Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012, but there are some OSes that it is not true for. Just adding this as a note if you're installing Windows and Linux: [the usual recommendation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) is to install Windows first and Linux second. This is because some (if not all) versions of Windows overwrite the bootloader with Linux-incompabtible software, locking you out of your Linux installation.

Windows handles dual-booting with other Windows versions very well. It doesn't always handle dual-booting with Linux so gracefully.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, computers follow a boot order.  What this means is it will look for an OS to boot into based off a list of connected devices (hard drives, USB sticks, CD drive, etc.) in a specified order which you can set in BIOS.

Having two separate hard drives means you can set the boot order list to be either the Windows 10 hard drive or the Window Server 2012 R2 hard drive.  Which ever is first in the list is what the computer will attempt to boot into first.  If there is an issue (such as the hard drive failure, or the hard drive becomes disconnected) it will look for the second device in the list and attempt to boot into the OS on that device. You can also override which device to boot into in BIOS for 1 time boots. You should be able to partition out a single hard drive as well to achieve a similar result.